# K8s ingress responding to multiple server names without having them configured?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, networking, dns, kubernetes-ingress

I'm pretty new to K8s in general and I'm a developer not exactly a network guy so I would like some ideas on how to reach my goal so I could research a bit on it.

Let's say I have my app (hosted on k8s), let's say myapp.domain.com.
Let's imagine I have a new customer, they want their own URL... let's say backoffice.company.com. For this to work I would have to go into my k8's ingress and add "backoffice.company.com" to the hosts.
Now let's imagine I have... 30000 customers doing this........... okay u get the point.

One idea that came to my mind was to use an external nginx for example which listens to all servernames and just proxies them to "myapp.domain.com". But this forces me to have an extra server just to serve as proxy :/

Is there a way, maybe via TXT records or something like that to make the ingress verify that the request is to 'myapp'?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may expose service directly to clients using Load Balancer and add wildcard dns CNAME record `*.company.com` pointing to Load Balancer. In that case you don't need Nginx Ingress which reduces latency for your clients and removes one possible bottleneck.

If you still want Nginx Ingress then you may use [hostname wildcards](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#hostname-wildcards) like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-wildcard-host
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "*.foo.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/foo"
        backend:
          service:
            name: service2
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, when you refer to using a Load Balancer I'm guessing it's an external LB right? possibly either AWS, GC, Cloudflare or any other 3party right?


Regarding the option of the nginx ingress, that wouldn't work because to do that I would need to have all my customers domains which is fine if it's a couple of them... but if I have dozens for example the ingress rules will become insane.

Comment: that's why I specified wildcard hostname like "*.foo.com". It matches all subdomains under foo.com, so you need only one record to match all your customers.

Comment: but my customers don't have all the same hostname, that's my point...
they could have like:

app.companyA.com
app.companyB.com
app.companyC.com
app.companyD.com
app.companyF.com

Comment: Then I don't see any way how you can help yourself. Because you anyway have to create all DNS records, right? Your task is too generic and possibly overly complex. I guess you should think how to reduce the complexity of the task. Also, i think you definitely will not be able to create 2nd level domain per customer, that will cost just insane amount of money.

Comment: there's a simple solution, having an external nginx which listens to no servername in particular and just proxy's requests to the k8s. It's quite simple to do, I was just trying to avoid having this extra layer.

I won't configure the customer's DNS's my intention was to have them configure it if they want to use a custom URL of their own.
This is something that I've seen done in a few SaaS products

Comment: What stops you from doing "*" host in Nginx Ingress? Nginx Ingress can also match all possible hostnames....

Comment: Indeed, this is something I thought about, but I have more applications in this k8s cluster.
I'm guessing if I create that ingress, all requests could end-up there right?
or is there a way to say, if none of the other ingress's are activated fall back to this generic one?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/209